# What kind of machine learning model would be best suited for correlated multiple outputs?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, python, random-forest

I have a dataset with 15 input columns, and 4 output column names. These 4 outputs are related to each other.

I have fitted four different GLM models to predict them.

But I want neural networks/random forests/other machine learning techniques.

What would be the best approach for this problem if I want to have:

1. A single model with multiple outputs (Continuous values)
2. Preferably gives me the distribution of the output rather than a single value.
3. Takes into account the correlation in the output space. These four values are somewhat related to each other. X1>X2>X3>X4 always.

Any articles/guides etc would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neural networks should work fine. As well as multivariate logistic regression (multiple dependent variables).

Comment: Would love some more details....

Comment: @maximusdooku What type of outputs are these? Continuous value, binary? And how do the four outputs relate to each other?

Comment: @horaceT Continuous values. I have provided more info in the question. But these are basically levels of flood.

Comment: Would love to get any responses.

Comment: I would try first a basic multilayer perceptron.